# Why variable that declared in a using statement treated as readonly?

Tags: c#, .net, using-statement, object-lifetime

why variable (myform) in using block treated as read-only and the compiler raise an error when I try to pass it as a reference to a function.

sample code:

```
using (Form myform = new Form)
{
    myfunc(ref myform);
}
```

passing using variable to a function as ref will raise an error. thus the code above will raise an error.

**Note** : 'readonly' keyword is unrelated to my question.

Comment: Eh, what's the question? I am not able to understand it...

Comment: IMO this should had stayed in the `using` question. To repeat my earlier question: *in what scenario would this be useful*, withou adding unnecessary confusion (that might be better handled with try/finally). Until there is a usage scenario, the complexity issues around "original value"/"final value" (and which gets disposed) makes it silly

Comment: @AtoMerZ - readonly keyword is used for fields.

Comment: Pro tip: Ensure that your question makes sense using the "instant preview" pane **before** submitting it. Editing within the allowed 5 minute window is great for answers, but doesn't work out so well for questions. People are pretty quick about trying to answer (and downvoting, and voting to close, etc.).

Comment: @Peter sorry removed. I tried gave me an error, turns out it wasn't about read my var being readonly...

Comment: Also (tags) using is not garbage collection... Just sayin'

Comment: It is a legitimate question, and the previous one got derailed into another direction.

Comment: @Henk I'm not sure it did; IMO the answer is pretty much the same as I replied there

Comment: Marc: Agreed. Except for maybe the 'why' part. I'd like to understand the reasons for the differences (see my answer) in handling these cases as well. I see no point in the intention i.e. the modification of the value, but the underlying reasoning are making my curious.

Comment: What the... I dont speak about readonly keyword.

Comment: I mean we can change reference value of using variable.

Comment: @LightWing and I *still* mean: show a genuine use-case.

Comment: Use case or not, I'd buy Eric Lippert a beer for an explanation. Really just as a convenience to prevent yourself from messing up? Or is there something more to it that I fail to see without more coffee?

Comment: My close vote was from back before this question made any sense (see my previous comment). As it no longer applies, I'm not sure why 4 other people agreed with me some time much later. Voting to re-open.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm looking at an (outdated?) spec [1] right now.

15.13 says that variables that you *declare* in the resource acquisition part are readonly. That is:

```
var form = new Form1();
using (form) {
    form = null;
}
```

works, but

```
using (var form = new Form1()) {
    form = null;
}
```

doesn't.
This answers part of the question (i.e. Why? Because it is part of the spec..), but I understand that this is not really satisfying. But why would you even want to do that?

---

Edit: After thinking about this, let me offer a possible explanation for this rule:

You have

```
using (var something = new Foo()) {
   something = /* whatever */
}
```

and the compiler allows this. Now what if Foo needs a lot of unmanaged resources (maybe that's the reason you wanted to use `using` in the first place)? After the using block you have no way to access this reference anymore. It wasn't disposed, because you reassigned `something` and forgot to handle it yourself. You don't have a guarantee that the GC runs, at all. Or when. You just created a resource leak that is obscured and hidden.

---

A final one, inspired by Henk's link to Eric Lippert's blog, which again just ends up throwing the spec at us:

> A using statement of the form
>
> using (expression) statement
>
> has the same two possible expansions, but in this case ResourceType is 
>   implicitly the compile-time type of the expression, and the resource variable 
>   is inaccessible in, and invisible to, the embedded statement.

In other words:

```
var form = new Form1();
using (form) {
    form = null;
}
```

works, because this is expanded to

```
var form = new Form1();
var invisibleThing = form;
try {
   form = null;
} finally {
    if (invisibleThing != null) ((IDisposable)invisibleThing).Dispose();
}
```

So in this case the fact that you have no influence over the `using` reference is just hidden from you and is exactly like in the previous case.

1:http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm

Comment: Already posted http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664736%28VS.71%29.aspx on the other question.

Comment: Also, the `using` statement needs the variable in order to be able to call `Dispose` on it. In fact, if you use `using (new Form()){}` the `using` statement will still be able to dispose the form. Apparently it creates its own variable to keep track of the instance.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean the variable instantiated at the start of a using block, then it's read only because it needs to be disposed at the end of the block. The point of a using block is to have a resource destroyed in a predictable way rather than waiting for the garbage collector to do it's job.

Comment: But it's only read-only if you _declare_ it inside the using block. A pre-declared var does not become readonly.

Comment: @Henk well, if it isn't declared there it is a completely different scenario; evaluating the result of an assignment expression. There ***is no*** using variable (available, at least) to discuss / contrast in that scenario

Comment: @Marc: just expression I guess, the assignment isn't crucial. Treating `using(var)` special would indeed be a 3rd scenario.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in your example there is most likely no reason for the `ref` modifier.

So you're asking a very theoretical question, it never is a problem in practice.

The annotated C#3 manual does not give an explanation.

Eric Lippert touches on the subject in a post [about (not) Boxing in a using statement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/14/to-box-or-not-to-box-that-is-the-question.aspx?PageIndex=4).

My own stab at it:

The compiler makes the controlled var readonly *because it can*. Leaving this var writeable would open up even more cans of worms, see the Boxing article from Eric. Note that a similar rule applies to the enclosed variable in a `foreach()`. Basically, writing to these vars would never be useful, so the compiler takes maximum control over them.

Comment: "So you're asking a very theoretical question, it never is a problem in practice." I know.

Comment: Garbage collector can free the variable if i change its reference.i can't understand why c# dont let us to change reference of Disposable Objects that apears as using variable.

Comment: @LightWing in using `using`, you are making a statement about the expected lifetime of that object. If you want to `null it *even earlier* (which, btw, is unlikely to make it collected any sooner) - use try/finally

Comment: Thanks for the link, Henk. I think the explanation is in there. Updated my answer a final time, although the question is closed now

Answer (score 1):

[readonly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is a keyword in C#. It's useful when you want to ensure the value never changes outside a constructor.

This keyword could be helpful when you're contributing code to a large project and you're worried coworkers might try to change a variable that should never be altered.

**Edit**: I'm curious why someone downvoted my answer. Whoever downvoted can you please show my where my answer is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Your answer isn't wrong. It just turns out that it's irrelevant. Later edits to the question by the asker (within the 5 minute window, of course, so there's no record of it in the edit history) revealed that he was talking about the `using` statement, rather than the `readonly` keyword combined with a regular variable. (Not my downvote, but since you asked... No worries, I made the same mistake before the question was clarified.)